# SQL Server Update With IF Statement

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL database that includes an upload date and birth date. I've added a column called "AgeFlag" which I'd like to equal "Over 40" if upload date - birth date is >= 40, and "Under 40" otherwise. I think this means I need an update statement with an IF statement, but I am uncertain how to proceed:

```
UPDATE datasetitems SET ageflag = SELECT IF((datediff(year, d.timestamp, di.birthdate)>40,'Over 40','Under 40') FROM datasetitems di JOIN datasets d ON di.datasetid = d.datasetid);
```

Maybe this would be easier with a temporary table to do the age calculation?

Comment: Design wise, since the age is transient and always change (except if you are only dealing with age of dead people), it is not a good idea to store it. If you need it like that you can compute it when doing a SELECT, based on `birthdate` or even doing a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CASE` expression rather than `IF` will do the job of your pseudo code. Here's an example, reversing the dates as @Seekwell74 noticed:

```
UPDATE datasetitems 
SET ageflag = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, di.birthdate, d.timestamp) > 40 THEN 'Over 40' ELSE 'Under 40' END 
FROM datasetitems di 
JOIN datasets d ON di.datasetid = d.datasetid;
```

However, your age calculation is wrong. `DATEDIFF` counts the number of year boundaries between the dates, not the interval in years. For example, `DATEDIFF` will result in 1 year between dates 2017-12-31 and 2018-01-01.

Below is another method to calculate a person's age:

```
UPDATE datasetitems 
SET ageflag = CASE WHEN (CAST(CONVERT(char(8), di.birthdate, 112) AS int) - CAST(CONVERT(char(8), d.timestamp, 112) AS int)) / 10000 > 40 THEN 'Over 40' ELSE 'Under 40' END 
FROM datasetitems di 
JOIN datasets d ON di.datasetid = d.datasetid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use as case statement:

```
UPDATE di 
SET ageflag = 
case 
    when datediff(year, di.birthdate, d.timestamp) > 40 
    then 'Over 40' 
    else 'Under 40' 
end
FROM datasetitems di JOIN datasets d 
ON di.datasetid = d.datasetid);
```

Also, I think your date parameters for datediff are reversed?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
UPDATE datasetitems 
    SET ageflag = case when abs(datediff(year, d.timestamp, di.birthdate))>40 then 'Over 40' else'Under 40' end
        FROM datasets d join datasetitems di ON di.datasetid = d.datasetid);
```